# form array from ajax call iterating through $.each()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want array in the following format

```
var day_data = [
  {"period": "2012-10-01", "licensed": 3407},
  {"period": "2012-09-30", "licensed": 3351},
  {"period": "2012-09-29", "licensed": 3269},
  {"period": "2012-09-20", "licensed": 3246},
  {"period": "2012-09-19", "licensed": 3257},
  {"period": "2012-09-18", "licensed": 3248},
  {"period": "2012-09-17", "licensed": 3171},
  {"period": "2012-09-16", "licensed": 3171},
  {"period": "2012-09-15", "licensed": 3201},
  {"period": "2012-09-10", "licensed": 3215}
];
```

From my ajax request i get data in object format

```
$(response).each(function(i,v){
                        my_data['period'] = v.period;
                        my_data['licensed'] = v.licensed;
                    });
```

I do this,
but my array is `[period: "2012-10-01", licensed: "3407"]`

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using eval() or json.Stringify

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

```
$(response).each(function(i,v){
   var temp={};
   temp.period = v.period;
   temp.licensed= v.licensed;
   my_data.push(temp);
});
```

I assume everything else is setup properly. The important thing is you want to for array of objects and my_data is array with different objects formed from temp object.

Comment: it gives me array in the [Object, Object, Object, Object] format ,i want in  {"period": "2012-09-16", "licensed": 3171},
  {"period": "2012-09-15", "licensed": 3201},
  {"period": "2012-09-10", "licensed": 3215} format

Comment: Then your response data is not in proper format. Check this fiddle.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb_satchitanand/cmHeL/2/)

Comment: i send data in the following format $data[0]['period'] = '2012-10-01';
        $data[0]['licensed'] = '3407';
        $data[1]['period'] = '2012-10-01';
        $data[1]['licensed'] = '3407';
        $data[2]['period'] = '2012-10-01';
        $data[2]['licensed'] = '3407';
        $data[3]['period'] = '2012-10-01';
        $data[3]['licensed'] = '3407';

Comment: Please check my fiddle in the previous comment and check where you are going wrong.